# Update column value of CSV in C#

Tags: c#

In the coding, I want to replace the column value of CSV. However, it can`t replace the value in CSV.

CSV file:

```
"Name","Age"
"michael","16"
"miko","15"
"Tom","24"
```

---

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.csv");
            TestDataModel users = new TestDataModel();
           
            text = users.Name.Replace("m", "n");

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.csv", text);

        }

        public class TestDataModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a useful thing, called debugger. I strongly advise to use it and inspect `text`  variable contents.

Comment: Same file you not able to append better user different file name or location.

Comment: What you are doing is creating empty model class, and never attaching your CSV data into it. Checkout deserialization/serialization topics to learn more how to deal with this kind of problems

Comment: You should really look in to the `CsvHelper` library. CSV files are way more complicated than you think they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a lot of misconception in code you provided, and some of the solutions for your problem might not be begginer friendly.
Especially when they are not 'global' solutions. For your case I tried to explain parts of code in comments

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var csvFilePath = @"C:\test.csv";

// Split csv file into lines instead of raw text.
string[] csvText = File.ReadAllLines(csvFilePath);

var models = new List<TestDataModel>();

// Regex that matches your CSV file.
// Explained here: https://regex101.com/r/t589CW/1
var csvRegex = new Regex("\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\"");
for (int i = 0; i < csvText.Length; i++)
{
    // Skip headers of file.
    // That is: "Name","Age"
    if (i == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // Check for potential white spaces at the end of the file.
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csvText[i]))
    {
        continue;
    }
    
    models.Add(new TestDataModel
    {
        // Getting a name from regex group match.
        Name = csvRegex.Match(csvText[i]).Groups[1].Value,
        
        // Getting an age from regex group and parse it into integer.
        Age = int.Parse(csvRegex.Match(csvText[i]).Groups[2].Value),
    });
}

// Creating headers for altered CSV.
string alteredCsv = "\"Name\",\"Age\"\n";

// Loop through your models to modify them as you wish and add csv text in correct format.
foreach (var testDataModel in models)
{
    testDataModel.Name = testDataModel.Name.Replace('m', 'n');
    alteredCsv += $"\"{testDataModel.Name}\",\"{testDataModel.Age}\"\n";
}

var outputFilePath = @"C:\test2.csv";
File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, alteredCsv);

public class TestDataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

However this answer contains many topics that you might want to get familiar with such as:

- Regex/Regex in C#
- Data Serialization/Deserialization
- Working with Linq
- String templates
- I/O Operations

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public static void Replace()
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.csv");
        string _text = text.Replace("m", "n");
        
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\New_test.csv", _text);
    }
```